# convert a Small Block interactions(MIT app inventor programming method) to a java code

Tags: java, app-inventor

is it possible to make a small and simple software which can provide the Block Programming (as that of MIT app inventor 2) and provide the java code for that specific method which has been just created using block programming ?
People are trying to convert whole Android Studio to MIT App inventor, instead there should be smaller program, which allows you to provide the java program once you have completed a method using block programming.

Comment: see this thread in the App Inventor forum https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/Fk3vK8xhx14/vLVSz3cuAwAJ